# VF page that includes a lightning app and an apex:tabPanel throws js error in browser console

Tags: visualforce, lightning-out

Summary
JS errors are thrown in browser console when including apex:includeLightning and apex:tabPanel in Visualforce. apex:tabPanel introduces scriptaculous which has conflicts with $A in aura.

Does anyone has a solution/workaroud for this issue which was also reported in 'Salesforce Known Issues' and is under review?

Known issue Link : https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018BlGQAU

Comment: did you find any workaround for this?

Comment: I ran into the same issue and the workaround I had to implement was to move the tabs into the aura component

Comment: @brezotom thank you!

Comment: @joe Posted my workaround as an answer.

Comment: Any still looking for a workaround for this, I have posted a hacky workaround as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Posting the workaround which I have used in the VF page.

We have removed the apex:tabpanel and replaced with HTML tabs with same design.

Link : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs

PS : This may not be usefull for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hacky workaround for this issue. Might not be suitable for all situations but would help in some scenarios.

Workaround:-

1. Create a new VF page and embed the lightning app / component
2. Embed the VF page into the original VF page inside an apex:iframe tag passing the necessary URL parameters

This is not a long term solution but can be used as a stop-gap solution until legacy Visualforce pages are rewritten in lightning.

Answer (score -1):

There is a tabpanel component in lightning you may use and following code should work for tabpanel:

```
    <aura:component>
        <lightning:tabset selectedTabId="one">
            <lightning:tab label="Item One" id="one">
                One Content !
            </lightning:tab>
            <lightning:tab label="Item Two" id="two">
                Two Content !
            </lightning:tab>
            <lightning:tab label="Item Three" id="three">
                Three Content !
            </lightning:tab>
        </lightning:tabset>
</aura:component>
```

more documentation : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:tab/example

Comment: Thanks, but it is not always practical to replace a large VF page with tabpanels into a lightning component at short notice.

Comment: Yes, there is salesforce known issue on that . So it's your best bet to use lightning component instead of using apex component , if you plan to migrate into lightning.

Comment: For anyone still looking for a workaround to this issue, I have posted a hacky fix that I found as an answer